# jQuery based checkbox not working

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataString="hy";
    var htmlnew="<input type='checkbox' name='formDoor' value='A' class='list' enable='true'>Check 1";

    alert(htmlnew);

    $(".list").change(function()
    {
        $("#regTitle").append(htmlnew);
    });
 });
```

The above is which i used when each time i check the checkbox with class list. i get a new one in `#regTitle` div, but the problem i am facing is the newly generated check boxes are not able to checked,can you guys tell me whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should delegate event handling with `on()` so that everything works also on newly added elements (jQuery > 1.7);

```
$("body").on("change", ".list", function()
{
$("#regTitle").append(htmlnew);
 });
```

if you use an older version of jQuery use delegate or live

```
$(document).delegate(".list","change", function()
{
$("#regTitle").append(htmlnew);
 });

$(".list").live("change", function()
{
    $("#regTitle").append(htmlnew);
});
```

Comment: it saying $("body").on is not a function

Comment: @AlexMathew then you have an older version of jQuery, use live or delegate()

Comment: but still nothing change, look the .delegate and .on is not working but live work

Comment: @AlexMathew that's strange because live is a shorthand version of delegate(), anyhow if it works, ok

Comment: but nicola, still i dont get the output as i desire, what i mean by live got worked is, its not shown any error

Comment: @AlexMathew post your markup becaus this should work, look here http://jsfiddle.net/PmNjK/

Comment: @AlexMathew that's why i told you, post your entire code, maybe it's something else (whatversion of jQuery are you  using?)

Comment: its a app for a client, cant share the code,wait let me see what can i share

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox's change event does not attach to the dynamically generated elements. You will have to delegate the bind. Using .on() is very good for this purpose.

```
$("body").on("change", ".list",function() {
    $("#regTitle").append(htmlnew);
});
```